# How to import anime.js to my Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, anime.js

I have a question regarding importing an `anime.js` into my vue project. I am using vue cli. How do I include `animejs` to my project? I tried it this way:

```
import anime from 'animejs'
Vue.use(anime);
```

but I get an error in the console that says:

> **Uncaught TypeError**: a.hasOwnProperty is not a function. . .

can you guys help me?

Comment: `Vue.use()` is used only for plugins designed for Vue.js. You can't just throw it there like this.

Comment: Can you please help me on this? Do I have to import animejs on every component? There is probably a better way right?

Comment: Yes you have to import it in every component that will use it.

Comment: Or you can create a Vue.js plugin and then you'll be able to use `Vue.use()`. Here is how you create plugins: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Comment: I see.I haven't touched on the vue plugins yet. Maybe i'll come to this problem when i get to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

`Vue.use()` is used only for plugins designed for Vue.js. You can't simply add a library there, it won't work.

My suggestion is that you create that plugin and use it on your project to make anime.js acessible everywhere.

You could do it like this:

```
//vue-anime.js
import anime from 'animejs';

const VueAnime = {
  install (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$animeJS = anime;
  }
}

export default VueAnime
```

Then later

```
import VueAnime from './vue-anime';
Vue.use(VueAnime);
```

Now every Vue component will be able to use anime acessing `this.$animeJS`.

Comment: Hi! Tried the code above. But why do I get undefined when I console.log(this.$animeJS) in one of the component?

Comment: Well this depends on a lot of stuff. It depends mostly on how your project looks like. My code is a basis for what you'll need to do.

Comment: can you check my code pls? https://github.com/ilbrigz/Vue-vue . Still a newbie and struggling. I really need some help at times or ill just end up leaving unsolved problems

Answer (score 2):

Or simply -

```
import Vue from "vue";
import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.min.js';

Vue.prototype.$anime = anime;
```

Then **this.$anime** in all components

Answer (score 1):

@Phiter's answer looked good at first, but I wasn't able to get it to work in my vue-cli 3 environment. The below code worked though, so I think it may work for you. This is just a simple way to install an external library into your Vue app and expose it through a prototype:

```
// animejs.js
import anime from 'animejs'

const install = (Vue, options) => {
    Vue.prototype.$animejs = anime
}

export default install
```

---

```
// Then, in your main.js (at least for me)
import VueAnime from './animejs'
Vue.use(VueAnime)
```

Now, when you need to access the library, just use `this.$animejs` in your project.

Answer (score 0):

or simply like this in main.js after `npm install`:

```
import anime from 'animejs';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$anime', { value: anime });
```

then use this.$anime tu use it.

Answer (score 0):

To use **AnimeJS** globally in **Vue 3** project, just create a plugin (*plugins/anime.js*):

```js
import anime from 'animejs';

export default {
  install(app, options) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$anime = anime;
  },
};
```

Then include it (*main.js or elsewhere*):

```js
import VueAnime from './plugins/anime';

createApp(App)
  .use(VueAnime)
  .mount('#app');
```

And now, it's accessible everywhere by `this.$anime`.

Please notice that a minor change from the previous version is [installing the plugin for Vue 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#writing-a-plugin).